# Python format_map method, how to deal with both for string and numbers missing cases?

Tags: python

In order to use the format_map method, I create a new dict class:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return '{' + key + '}'
```

I have one dict variable d:

```
d = MyDict({"k2":2,"k3":3})
```

Then in the logic, I could use it like this:

```
# Case 1: the below format_map line will not raise errors
# and s still be the same original value: 'xxx{k1}yyy'
# since k1 does not exist from the passing dict

s = 'xxx{k1}yyy'.format_map(d)
```

But this solution doesn't work for the numbers case:

```
# Case 2: this below line will raise the error: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'
s = 'xx{i:02d}yy'.format_map(d)
```

It's because the `__missing__` method returned a string, but here it requires a number type. For this case I want the s keep unchanged and without throw an exception

```
# Case 3: Case 1 + Case 2 
s = 'xxx{k2}yyy{i:02d}zz'
# for this case I want the s to be changed to: 'xxx2yyy{i:02d}zz'
```

Question: How to make the case 2 and case 3 scenarios work as well as case 1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you are trying to do. But I will assume i is a variable previously defined and you want the value to replace a missing dictionary key. Then you could use:

```
i = 5
s = f'xx{i:02d}yy'.format_map(d)
```

giving output

`xx05yy`

Comment: In order to accept the missing keys and not raised errors, I added the customized \_\_missing__ method. But my version is only working for none positional argument cases. For the position case like {i:02d} it will still raise error when i is not defined before the formatting. I'm writing a tool that can accept the user's inputs, and the user's inputs can be any formats. If the user forgot to define the i in first place, my code will raise errors.